# NSStream close in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, background, nsstream

Im developing a navigation app that using NSStream to manage a TCP connection with my server. Every time the app gets new coordinates it sends it to the server.

The problem is when my app goes to background and then suspended the stream get closed and i cant keep sending the updates to the server.

Can someone help me here? i'm pretty lost..

Comment: Sending updates via a TCP (always-on) connection for a location tracking app seems incredibly inefficient to me. Have you considered using something more like UDP, or even HTTP posts?

Comment: Actually i didnt consider it at the time i have started the developing and now it is to late for me to change the whole design, also the app does a lot more then location tracking so TCP is more comfortable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try ASIHTTPRequest, It support background task.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-asihttprequest.html